# Eclipse stopped uploading apk files on device

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

As usually Eclipse doing stupid things with no reason. First I created the project and connected my device to PC. Everything worked perfectly - apk file was executing in run and dubug mode just fine. I changed some code, added permission to manifest file and that's it - Eclipse no longer upload my apk on device. I already saw those problems like year ago when I wanted to start Android coding, but quited due to Eclipse being absolutely horrible IDE on Windows and google not supporting good IDEs. Anyone can provide the solution to my problem?

Comment: Besides bashing on Eclipse, could you give more details about what it does and does not.

Comment: Besides asking for irrelevant information could you explain why this IDE crashes every 5 minutes and basically you have to spend alot more time on researching solutions to it's problems rather than developing android application itself?

Comment: -1 expecially for your follow up comment, because the old aphorism about a bad workman and his tools comes to mind. I use Eclipse on Windows 8-10 hours a day, 5-7 days of the week, if it crashed every 5 minutes I'd be out of a job.

Comment: It crashes because you've done something wrong. The "irrelevant information" is causing your issues. As @paulkayuk said. I've been using Eclipse as my main IDE for many years and didn't have your issues. Therefore the issue is with the user not the IDE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happened a year ago already, then maybe your debug key is expired. Delete your debug.keystore then rebuild you app in Eclipse. Eclipse/ADT will create a new debug key that remains valid for another year.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode

Comment: Thank you, seems it helped me. I installed ADT few days ago tho.

Answer (score 0):

Is the device showing up in the "Devices" tab? If not, you can try restarting adb.

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

Comment: It is showing. Restarting adb doesnt change anything. Restarting Eclipse+adb+device doesnt change anything either.